# Sort MySQL results by a column with several values separated by a period

Tags: mysql

I suspect this may have already been asked, but I'm not sure how to phrase the question so that SO search engine picks it up.

I have a column called TCID, which contains values in this format:

```
1.A.1.1.1
4.A.1.1.1
2.B.1.1.10
2.B.1.1.2
...
```

There are 5 units in this TCID, separated by periods. I want the position to the left to take the highest priority, and then finally the last digit is the lowest priority.

So it would sort like this:

```
1.A.1.1.1
2.B.1.1.2
2.B.1.1.10
4.A.1.1.1
```

Here is the query I have so far. It almost works, but the last position is not getting sorted.

```
SELECT * 
FROM system 
WHERE cluster = \"$tc_name\"
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR( SUBSTRING_INDEX(tcid,'.',1) , 1 ) AS UNSIGNED),
         SUBSTR( SUBSTRING_INDEX(tcid,'.',2) , LENGTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX(tcid,'.',1)) + 2 ),
         CAST(SUBSTR( SUBSTRING_INDEX(tcid,'.',3) , LENGTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX(tcid,'.',2)) + 2 ) AS UNSIGNED),
         CAST(SUBSTR( SUBSTRING_INDEX(tcid,'.',4) , LENGTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX(tcid,'.',3)) + 2 ) AS UNSIGNED)
```

Can anyone help me fix this or suggest a better way to do this?

Comment: better way is to store them in 4 separate fields and in your application code, concat and use them as required

Comment: I think we can all suggest a better way :-(

Comment: @Raven also, in your existing query, dont cast the last part of the string as Unsigned, and try!

Comment: @Madhur Bhaiya, I tried un-casting the last section and it seems to produce the same result!

Answer (score 0):

There are obviously better ways to store this information in the database, such as storing the values in separate fields. However, it's not always possible to change the code base to do such things.

But I believe you just need to add the final order by to your query in order to for it to work as expected;

```
SELECT *
FROM system
WHERE cluster = "<some search term>"
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR( SUBSTRING_INDEX(tcid,'.',1) , 1 ) AS UNSIGNED),
         SUBSTR( SUBSTRING_INDEX(tcid,'.',2) , LENGTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX(tcid,'.',1)) + 2 ),
         CAST(SUBSTR( SUBSTRING_INDEX(tcid,'.',3) , LENGTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX(tcid,'.',2)) + 2 ) AS UNSIGNED),
         CAST(SUBSTR( SUBSTRING_INDEX(tcid,'.',4) , LENGTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX(tcid,'.',3)) + 2 ) AS UNSIGNED),
         CAST(SUBSTR( SUBSTRING_INDEX(tcid,'.',5) , LENGTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX(tcid,'.',4)) + 2 ) AS UNSIGNED);
```

Please see this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2096/1) to check

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun...

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT '1.A.1.1.1' x
UNION ALL
SELECT '4.A.1.1.1'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2.B.1.1.10'
UNION ALL
SELECT '2.B.1.1.2'
) a
ORDER BY
INET_ATON(CONCAT(MID(x,1,1),MID(x,4,1000)));
```